# Iterate Napi::Object Properties (Keys) in Node.js C++ N-API

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-napi

I am having a problem using c++ n-api api and I have reviewed the documentation [here](https://nodejs.github.io/node-addon-api/class_napi_1_1_object.html), and I do not see a way to iterate the keys of a `Napi::Object`. I must be missing something because this is possible in JavaScript, so it must be possible in the C++ API.

How can I list or iterate the keys (properties) in a Napi::Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the Doxygen documentation which Google surfaced at `https://nodejs.github.io/node-addon-api/` is out-of-date.

The right place to look is on the Node.js Github repo at https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/master/napi.h

Looking at the correct header version, `Napi::Object` has a function `GetPropertyNames()` which is exactly what I needed (though it is oddly not `const`).